# C++ tries to delete a pointer that doesn't exist

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a small text based game I'm working on, and I have a function that basically ends the game if the user selects the option via this line of code:

```
void MainMenu::Exit()
{
    std::exit(0);
}
```

This is fine and all, but the MainMenu destructor is called, which contains a delete call to a pointer I created with the new keyword (therefore I think I need to manually delete the object before exiting the program). The object is my world class, which is created when the user selects play. However, the user can exit the main menu before the world pointer is created, so the compiler doesn't know where the pointer points to. I tried changing the destructor to see if the world object was NULL, like this:

```
MainMenu::~MainMenu()
{
    if(world != NULL)
         delete world;
}
```

But I still get a popup window telling me that my program has stopped responding, and I need to manually kill it.

Essentially my question is, is there a way to tell if a pointer is actually pointing to something? Do I even need to manually handle the deletion of the pointer?

Comment: That null check is redundant.

Comment: What does your constructor for `MainMenu` look like? Are you initializing `world` with 0?

Comment: Do note that in general, you shouldn't need a destructor or even `delete` because you should use things such as `std::vector` and smart pointers that manage the memory they own. Doing manual memory management can get out of hand quickly.

Comment: Always initialize a pointer (if not static the pointer is not initialized to zero) and just delete the pointer (you can omit the test for zero)

Comment: I realize now the null check is redundant, oops. I never initialize `world` until the user hits play, but the user has the option to hit exit before play, thus resulting in a pointer that has never been created.

Comment: @chris How would that help (honestly)? I'm pretty new to C++, so I have no idea what a vector really is (I think it is similar to an arraylist in Java; a dynamic list), but I have no idea how it could help me in my situation.

Comment: @user3316633, Well, `std::vector` wouldn't for this specific problem, but it would in general if you use `new[]` normally. The smart pointers are what would help here. A smart pointer is like a normal one that cleans up after itself, so no need for a destructor or Rule of Three worries, or leaking if an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in C++ you must ensure that every 'new' is matched with a 'delete'. You should ensure in MainMenu ctor that you are initializing world to NULL (or preferrably nullptr if your compiler supports it):

```
MainMenu::MainMenu (/* more stuff here */) : world (nullptr)
{
// more stuff here
}
```

Also, as chris points out, you do not have to test for NULL when deleting:

```
MainMenu::~MainMenu()
{
delete world; // no-op if world is null
}
```

Not sure why your program is hanging, though. Seems that it should seg fault if you are not initializing 'world' to null.

Comment: Thank you, I come from Java where that is dangerous to do, but it fixed the problem!

Comment: I second the use of std::unique_ptr. Simply declare world thusly: std::unique_ptr<WorldClass> world(new WorldClass); and deletion is managed for you.

Comment: thank you, simple and easy to understand! But wait, can I use smart pointers in heap space? I thought stack space took care of the deletion of pointers automatically when the object isn't in scope anymore. Edit, never mind, didn't notice the new keyword in there...

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the pointer in constructors of the class. The destructor can be written without the check whether the pointer is equal to NULL or not.

```
MainMenu::~MainMenu()
{
         delete world;
}
```

Also it is much better to use a standard smart pointer as for example `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: Can you elaborate as to what a smart pointer is? I'm reading a C++ book that is updated for C++ 11, and so far I haven't been told to use anything but pointers (not the "smart" version).

Comment: I would add a `world = NULL` after a delete, because it's good practice and might help OP catch other bugs.

Comment: @AndyG I thought the whole point of `delete` was to delete the actual pointer to the block of memory that the pointer points to (horribly explained), so how would setting the pointer to null do anything? Is it just a safeguard to make sure that the pointer is actually severed?

Comment: @user3316633: If you set the pointer to NULL after deleting it, you can check for `== NULL` later to make sure you aren't doing anything with a deleted or uninitialized pointer. It's good practice to set pointers to `NULL` when you declare them, too, if you aren't immediately allocating memory for them. In summary, think of `NULL` as a special value you can check to make sure the pointer is actually pointing to allocated memory. Otherwise, when you delete, the pointer still points to a place in memory, but it's garbage/undefined.

Comment: @AndyG, In general, if using raw pointers, then yes, setting it to null probably has benefits that outweigh disadvantages, but after a destructor runs, you'll never see it again :)

Comment: @user3316633 A smart pointer is a class wrapper around a raw pointer that delete the object it refers to itself. So you need not bother about delete the object. You should read description of smart pointers in some documentation. I think you could find many references to smart pointers in the internet.

Comment: @chris: In general, yes, but I could create some toy examples where one performs branching based on whether a pointer is NULL or not. Even smart pointers generally have some way to check for NULL for this reason. Nowadays there are very few applications that can justify using raw pointers over managed ones.